# Is it possible to import a Jaxx walet into Mist?

Tags: mist, wallets, light-clients, jaxx

I have installed Jaxx on my smartphone and have some ETH in it, I've sen a small amount to the DAO address. If I at a later stage want to intereact with the DAO and Jaxx doesn't allow for this, is it possible to import my Jaxx wallet into Mist?

Jaxx is a deterministic wallet right? A bit like MultiBit HD is for Bitcoin? So does Mist allow for importing a wallet with a mnemonic key? Or is that feature planned? Or can I assume another wallet will come along in the future that has full capabilities and will be able to i;port my Jaxx wallet?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but one alternative would be to create a new account in Mist and send your Jaxx funds to your new account address from your phone. Rather simplistic, and possibly not a viable solution for you, but worth a mention.

Comment: I ended making an online wallet with MyEtherWallet and sending my ETH to there and getting DAO tokens that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main concern was not being able to access the DAO tokens I purchased with ETH from my Jaxx wallet. I opened Jaxx today and there is a new, DAO tab which has my tokens! Do no need to import into Mist to access my DAO. Great job Jaxx! [image: DAO tab in Jaxx]